# Rails 3.2.1 development mode terribly slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Why is my Rails development environment so terribly slow? I am seeing 2-3 seconds in the log for a call, the actually time is about 10 seconds for a controller action. A good chunk of time seems to be spent on the asset pipeline.

Gems like rails-dev-tweaks do not really help so far.

- My Setup:
- OS X fully updated
- Ruby 1.9.3-p0 via rvm
- Rails 3.2.1
- MySQL installed via homebrew
- Server POW or webrick

log output:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-10 13:14:34 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (40.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2084ms (Views: 44.6ms | ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

Comment: Wonder if you've somehow set the asset pipeline to recompile static assets on each request somehow?  Care to post your asset-related settings from your environment.rb/development.rb files?

Comment: If it's code problem, wrap with Benchamark and you will narrow it down.

Comment: App is generated from a devise/rspec/cucumber... app template https://gist.github.com/1790241

Comment: OK I found what did it, it was the Rails Footnotes gem that came with the app template. https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber

Beware!

Comment: @user1202128 I agree with Platinum Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured out what made it slow. It was the Rails Footnotes gem that came with the app template from: http://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber

I have also created an issue on github:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/issues/22